# How do you use CSS to format an image in parallel to multiple divisions in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I working on my integration of JS into my HTML and I want my web page to look some what presentable for a low level programmer. I've tried putting different divisions around and image (so two on the left vertically aligned and then an image the is the height of them combined in the gap on the right to fill the rest of that row. 
I've tried the normal method of:

```
#insertDivIdHere{
   float:left;
}
#otherDivIdHere{
   float:left;
}
#insertImgIdHere{
   float:left;
}
```

This method ends up with some weird formatting issues where the divisions overlap and the objects (ie buttons and text boxes) disappear and the image is to low.

Here is the HTML and CSS if you want to try it out (but I've left out my JS because I see no point in sharing it:

```css
#header{
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color:lightsteelblue;
    padding:12px;
    text-align:center;
}
#form{    
    
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
}
#formdiv {
    background-color: lightcyan;
    padding:12px;
    height: 200px;
    width:300px;
    float: left;
    
}
#ageRange{
    height: 30px;
    width: 120px;
}
#ageRangeDiv{
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding:12px;
    height:140px;
    width:300px;
    float: left;
    
}
#creds{
    border-radius: 5%;
    box-shadow: lightskyblue;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    padding:3px;
}
#age{
    border-radius: 5%;
    box-shadow: lightskyblue;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    padding:3px;
}
#image{
    width: auto;
    height: 340px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600,700"rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Intergration</title>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Web intergration</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="formdiv" name="formdiv">
                <form id="form" name="form">
                    First Name <input type="text" name="firstName" ><br>
                    <br>
                    Last Name <input type="text" name="lastName" ><br>
                    <br>
                    Email <input type="email" name="email"><br>
                </form>
                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                <button type="button" id="creds" onclick="validCreds()">Confirm</button>
            </div>

            <div id="ageRangeDiv">
                <form id="ageRange" name="ageRange">
                    <input type="radio" name="R1" id="U13" checked>Under 13 <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="R1" id="U18">13-18 <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="R1" id="U30">19-30 <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="R1" id="U50">31-50 <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="R1" id="O50">Over 50 <br>
                </form>
                <br><br><br><br>
                <button type="button" id="age" onclick="validAge()">Confirm</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="eve.jpg" id="image">
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ditch the idea of using floats... Go onto mdn or code accademy and have a look at css flex and css grid, they can do way more allot easier and (this might trigger some) would be considered a modern standard to web development.

Comment: Looking back on this, I was a pretty bad programmer, still am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how to use the `inline-flex` to align your content i hope you can modify them to do your layout.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}

.container>div+div {
  margin: auto;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container div:not(first-child) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div>
 
    <div>
      1
    </div>
    
    <div>
      2
    </div>
    
  </div>

  <div>
    3
  </div>
  
</div>
```